# DeviceExtendedProperties.GetValue throws exception ArgumentOutOfRangeException for property "IsApplicationPreinstalled"

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

I  want to know if the application is preinstalled or downloaded from market place on windows phone 8 platform.

For that i used http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.info.deviceextendedproperties

```
Boolean isPreinstalled = (Boolean)DeviceExtendedProperties.GetValue("IsApplicationPreinstalled");
```

Application throws exception as ArgumentOutOfRangeException - The specified property does not exist. However documentation does not indicate this property is deprecated. Am i missing something here ?

Comment: Did you add the ID_CAP_IDENTITY_DEVICE capability as per the MSDN article?

Comment: yes i did, if capability was missing then i would have got UnauthorizedAccessException exception.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have Windows Phone 8 **WITH** Update 3 installed. In older versions of the OS, ArgumentOutOfRangeException is thrown. The documentation does not mention this restriction.